# How to allow other users to run power query (which generates data from SQL Server) in Excel 2016

Tags: sql-server, excel, passwords, powerquery

We have created an excel in which shows data generated from SQL Server using power query, and want to share it with other users. The excel refreshes all tables using VBA's ThisWorkBook.Connections.("QuerName").Refresh to run all queries.

The Problem is that:
When we share this excel to co-workers from other departments, the excel requires new users to enter UserName and Password for SQL database instead of use the Username and Password we entered during creating this excel.

We found that Microsoft doesn't allow us to embed the database UserName and Password in Powerquery/VBA, and the Microsoft Query is not working. We are wondering if there is any way we could allow other users to refresh the data (run the query) directly instead of entering UaserName and Password.

Any suggestions would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Yes, the Excel file asks for credentials (SQL Authentication), but once this is entered, the Username & Password is stored in file - so no need to specify it again...

Comment: unless you would like it to use windows authentication, which I prefer. You'll have to create the windows authenticated users in SSMS, then they will be able to access SQL via Windows Authentication. Please advise which option you prefer?

Comment: Hi @Birel, thank you so much for your reply. If we created a Windows Authentication, does it mean the user with this Authentication would be able to login to the sql server and change our tables and data? What we thought is the user could only browse the data generated in the excel instead of messing up the data base. Is this possible? Right now, I think windows authentication might be the best way since I cannot find other solutions.

Comment: It all depends what permissions you give them when creating their uses in SQL... I personally think Windows Auth is the way to go...

Comment: Thank you very much for your suggestion Birel, but our Server Team doesn't want to create so many Windows Auth since we are going to share this excel with many co-workers. I'm going to try if there is another way and keep this as the backup solution.